# Wordpress domain mapping alias 302 redirection

Tags: wordpress, alias, http-status-code-302, domain-mapping

I want to build a Wordpress multisite with differents domains :

- mainblog.com (I installed wordpress on this url)
- mainblog.com/blog1
- mainblog.com/blog2

This works well.

I made 2 alias :

- site1.com/blog > mainblog.com folder
- site2.com/blog > mainblog.com folder

I installed [WordPress MU Domain Mapping](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) and mapped the domains :

- site1.com/blog on mainblog.com/blog1
- site2.com/blog on mainblog.com/blog2

When I type site1.com/blog or site2.com/blog, I redirect (302) on mainblog.com.
Have you an idea ?